# Passing delegates as parameters for mediator/subscriber pattern

Tags: c#, events, delegates, parameters, mediator

I'm looking for the appropriate and elegant way to create Mediator/Subscriber architecture with typed callbacks.

Let's suppose I have a class with 'events' i.e. delegates:

```
public class E
{
    public delegate void SomethingHappened (float a, int b);
    public delegate void ProgressFinished (int[] c);
}
```

Now I want to create a Mediator class that would register callbacks to those delegates and dispatch callbacks with supplied parameters:

```
public class Mediator
{
    public static void Register ( ???, Action callback)
    {
        // supplied delegate += callback
    }

    public static void Dispatch ( ???, params object[] list)
    {
        // executing supplied delegate with params: delegate(list)
    }
}
```

So I could use it the following way:

```
// Class A:
Mediator.Register (E.SomethingHappened, OnSomethingHappened);
private void OnSomethingHappened (float a, int b)
{
    //..........
}

// Class B:
Mediator.Dispatch (E.SomethingHappened, 0.1f, 'qwe');
```

Now the problem is that I can't pass delegate as parameter to Register or Dispatch. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: I think you've misunderstood delegates. A delegate *is* a callback (or can be used as it) - you don't register a callback *with* a delegate. Perhaps you're actually looking for events instead?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JonSkeet: I believe OP wanted to register a concrete callback method based on its delegate type, but didn't know how to pass the delegate type to the method

Comment: @JonSkeet yep Groo is right, I want exactly that

Comment: In that case, the comment of "supplied delegate += callback" is particularly confusing... as is the example where you're trying to convert the `OnSomethingHappened` method group to an `Action`, when `Action` doesn't have any parameters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a different approach: let your senders dispatch *messages*, and have your mediator dispatch them to different handlers based on their type.

Using generics, this would be refactored to:

```
// handlers should be differentiated by message type
public class SomethingHappenedMessage
{
    public float A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
}

public class Mediator
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, object> _dict = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

    public void Register<Tmessage>(Action<Tmessage> callback)
    {
        _dict[typeof(Tmessage)] = callback;
    }

    public void Dispatch<Tmessage>(Tmessage msg)
    {
        var handler = _dict[typeof(Tmessage)] as Action<Tmessage>;
        handler(msg);
    }
}
```

Or, you might have multiple handlers for each message type:

```
public class Mediator
{
    readonly Dictionary<Type, List<object>> _handlersByType = new Dictionary<Type, List<object>>();

    public void Register<Tmessage>(Action<Tmessage> callback)
    {
        List<object> handlers;
        if (!_handlersByType.TryGetValue(typeof(Tmessage), out handlers))
            _handlersByType[typeof(Tmessage)] = handlers = new List<object>();

        handlers.Add(callback);
    }

    public void Dispatch<Tmessage>(Tmessage msg)
    {
        List<object> handlers;
        if (!_handlersByType.TryGetValue(typeof(Tmessage), out handlers))
            return;

        foreach (Action<Tmessage> handler in handlers)
            handler(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks pretty good. Seems like I can't reduce boilerplate Tmessage declaration any further?

Comment: @VincentPride: I guess there might be a way to dissect a delegate type using reflection, but imho this is by far the cleanest approach. You can declare any message class, anywhere, and register its handler here. Also, for looser coupling, note that I made all methods instance (vs your static ones) so that you can pass the mediator around.